# How to override md-datepicker functionality using decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I'm overridding md-datepicker functionality using $provide.decorator for md-datepicker element.

What I want to achieve here is I would like to mark input field (child node of md-datepicker) should be marked readonly so that user can't enter date value manually and forced to select date from md-datepicker.

Input field gets readOnly property and it becomes readonly. but when I select the date using calender of md-datepicker - it gives me following error -

- TypeError: Cannot read property '$setTouched' of null
- TypeError: Cannot read property '$setViewValue' of null

**What's wrong with element after directive decorator runs ? Pls help.**

my decorator looks like this :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('Application_Name').config(['$provide', function($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('mdDatepickerDirective', [
        '$delegate',

        /**
         * @function mdDatepickerDirective
         * @description decorates mdDatepickerDirective to extend functionality:
         *              - Mark input field as read-only so which will prevent user from typing date manually
         *                and should select from date-picker calender only.
         * @param {angular.Directive} $delegate
         * @returns {angular.Directive} $delegate
         */
        function mdDatePickerDecorator($delegate) {
            var directive = $delegate[0];
            var compile = directive.compile;

            directive.compile = function (tElement) {
                tElement.find("input").prop("readOnly", "true");
            };

            return $delegate;

        }
    ]);
}])})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a new directive to solve this :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('Application_Name').directive('mcReadOnly', readOnly);

function readOnly() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
        element.find("input")[0].setAttribute("readonly","true");
        element.find("input").bind('click', function(e){
            element.find("button")[0].click();
        });
    }
}})();
```